# How to create pagination with angularjs with ngrepeat and bootstrap ui?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

What is the simpliest way to create pagination ?
I'd liket to use ng-repeat where i go through the items list and every item has id and name attributes. The next code works for example 15 items and show 2 page but i'd like to  show the first page the first 10 item and the other page shows the other items...and so on if i have a lot of items.

My code what i tried:

```
<table>
    <thead><th>id</th><th>name</th></thead>
    <tbody><tr ng-repeat="item in items">
        <td>{{item.id}}</td>
        <td>{{item.name}}</td>
    </tr></tbody>
</table>
<uib-pagination total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage" max-size="maxSize" class="pagination-sm" boundary-links="true" force-ellipses="true"></uib-pagination>
<script>
$scope.items = [] //here i have for example 15 items..it comes through rest
totalItems = $scope.items.length; //15
$scope.currentPage=1;//1. page
$scope.maxSize=4; //maximum 4 page show
</script>
```

Could someone helps to me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Are you trying to show a fixed number of items per page? Or are you dynamically trying to control the number of items per page?

Comment: the ui-bootstrap default is 10 per page so i just want to show in one page the first 10 item the second page the last 5....if 35 items comes: first page 10 second 10 third 10 and finally 5.

Comment: So i'd like to allow maximum 10 item per page, and do pagination when i have more than 10 item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at the fiddler [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pratikjs/6kwdd0yq/). Basically I have created a custom filter which will take the current page number and page size as input and then slice out the items that needs to be shown in the UI.

**Filter**

```
myApp.filter('paginate', function() {
  return function(items, page, pageSize) {
    if (items === undefined || items === null)
      return [];
    if (pageSize === undefined || pageSize === null || pageSize < 0 || pageSize >= items.length)
      return items;
    var filtered = [];
    page = page - 1;
    console.log(page * pageSize + " " + parseInt((page * pageSize) + pageSize));
    filtered = items.slice(page * pageSize, parseInt((page * pageSize) + pageSize));
    return filtered;
  }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="item in items | paginate: currentPage : pageSize">
    {{item}}
  </div>
  <input type="number" ng-model="currentPage" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use ui-bootstrap's [pagination directive](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/pagination)